# Find common columns between two users or null/zero if there is none

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I find common columns between 2 users but returning a zero result if there is none, that means returning a result even if there is no common columns.

```
SELECT u.usr_id, u.usr_fname, u.usr_lname, COUNT(ul.ulnk_lnk_id) AS common_links
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN user_links AS ul ON ul.ulnk_usr_id=u.usr_id
WHERE u.usr_id != $user_id
AND ul.ulnk_lnk_id IN
(SELECT l.ulnk_lnk_id FROM user_links AS l WHERE l.ulnk_usr_id=$user_id) 
GROUP BY u.usr_id HAVING common_links >= 0 ORDER BY common_links DESC";
```

This will return results that have 1 or more common columns between the users,
I need to return a result that also include 0 common columns...

Comment: Why `HAVING common_links >= 0`? I would have thought that rule would always be true since COUNT() can't be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your where clause is excluding any users that don't have a link in common. Moving the `ul.ulnk_lnk_id` check into the `ON` clause should correct the issue.

```
SELECT u.usr_id, u.usr_fname, u.usr_lname, COUNT(ul.ulnk_lnk_id) AS common_links
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN user_links AS ul ON (ul.ulnk_usr_id=u.usr_id AND ul.ulnk_lnk_id IN
(SELECT l.ulnk_lnk_id FROM user_links AS l WHERE l.ulnk_usr_id=$user_id) )
WHERE u.usr_id != $user_id
GROUP BY u.usr_id 
ORDER BY common_links DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT u.usr_id, u.usr_fname, u.usr_lname, COUNT(ul.ulnk_lnk_id) AS common_links
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN user_links AS ul ON ul.ulnk_usr_id=u.usr_id
WHERE u.usr_id != $user_id
AND ul.ulnk_lnk_id IN
(SELECT l.ulnk_lnk_id FROM user_links AS l WHERE l.ulnk_usr_id=$user_id) 
GROUP BY u.usr_id  ORDER BY common_links DESC";
```